# How can I use AppleScript to address dialog box in Ableton Live?

Tags: applescript, ableton-live

I have a collection of Ableton Live files (extension ".als") that I need to cycle through while playing a show. I'd like to dedicate a keyboard shortcut to launch each one, and had intended to use AppleScript for this.

The issue is that each file gets changed as I go through the process of playing the associated song, so that when I press the keyboard shortcut to launch the .als associated with the next song in my set, Ableton opens the "Save changes before closing?" dialog box (at which point what I want to do is select "Don't Save").

Simply pressing command + D at this point will do the trick, but I'd really like to automate this keypress. I can't seem to figure out how to get applescript to do this. I'm an applescript noob, and clicking the "Open Dictionary" option in AS seems to show that Ableton is not officially a scriptable app.

Any thoughts on this? Here's an example of an AppleScript I've been trying. This starts the process of opening the next .als in my set list, but won't click the "Don't Save" button.

```
tell application "Finder"
activate
open document file "Song 1.als" of folder "Desktop" of folder "User" of folder "Users" of startup disk
end tell
tell application "System Events"
keystroke "d" using command down
end tell
```

Comment: Maybe I should say that I'm definitely willing to opt for an Automator solution as well.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting!

Finally came across tips that made it work:

- Add both the Script Editor and Ableton Live to the Accessibility API:
  System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy...
- Ignore application responses to continue the script during dialog.

LiveLoader.scpt:

```
-- open file
ignoring application responses -- don't wait for user input
    tell application "Ableton Live 9 Suite" to open "Users:username:Desktop:LiveSet Project:LiveSet.als"
end ignoring

-- use delay if needed
-- delay 0.5

-- skip saving file
tell application "System Events"
    set frontmost of process "Live" to true
    key code 123 -- left
    key code 123 -- left
    keystroke return -- enter
end tell
```

Note:
 
Consider possible security impact. 
Perhaps simply disable apps in Privacy List after use. (Could be scripted ;)

Can now also send mouse clicks, for more creativeness. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old. but in the interest of helping others who might find themselves here... heres what i have done.

use a program call Qlab. the free version will be fine. 
make an applescript Cue. go to the 'trigger' tab. select midi trigger. hit the midi key you would like to assign the command too. this cue will now launch when it receives this midi note - even when running in the background.
go to the 'script' tab. copy and paste the script below.

you can make the relevant adjustments for each song. Basically each key will close all current ableton files without saving - as requested. and then launch a specific live set. which ever one you have assigned. in this case, the song 'Less Than Nothing'

the code...

```
tell application "System Events"
    set frontmost of process "Live" to true
    keystroke "q" using command down
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke (ASCII character 28) --left arrow
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke (ASCII character 28) --left arrow
    keystroke return
end tell
delay 2.0
do shell script "open '/Users/CamMac/Desktop/Less Than Nothing 2 .als' "
```